# GSM bit-error rate in Android

Tags: android, gsm, at-command, telephonymanager

I'm trying to get GSM bit-error rate in android. For this, I'm using `PhoneStateListener's` method `onSignalStrengthChanged()`. However, this always returns -1. I read in TS 27.007 section 8.5 (GSM AT commands from ETSI) that a manufacturer is free to provide or not to provide standard interface to obtain BER. Since, I'm getting -1 every time, I assume it is the limitation of my device hardware! Is there any workaround, so that I can obtain a valid BER (or RxQual in dedicated mode)? So far, I've been using the following code, but it's not working:

```
private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
   {
     @Override
     public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
     {
      super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);           
         x=String.valueOf(signalStrength.getGsmBitErrorRate());
     addToListView("GSM BER: " + x);
     }
  }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!